# Change order of _unhandled_key_input() being called

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a scene as such:
[image]

and this small script attached to both `A` & `B`:

```
extends Node2D

func _unhandled_key_input(event):
    print(self," _unhandled_key_input")
```

and whenever I press a key I get the following output:

```
B:[Node2D] _unhandled_key_input
A:[Node2D] _unhandled_key_input
```

Is it possible to change the order of `_unhandled_key_input` being invoked **without** changing the hierarchy of the nodes in the main scene?

i.e. the output changes to:

```
A:[Node2D] _unhandled_key_input
B:[Node2D] _unhandled_key_input
```

I tried changing the `process_priority` but that seems to have no effect

(using version 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

No.

From the godot 4 source: `_unhandled_key_input` is called on all nodes sequentially from `SceneTree::_call_input_pause`.
This method eventually relies on `Node::is_greater_than` to determines the order of the nodes. Nothing but their order in the tree is considered. `process_priority` is not relevant here.

However I would advise to reconsider your design, if you really require a specific order of calling `_unhandled_key_input`. Sounds a bit fragile.

Comment: would it be possible in 3.5? I forgot to mention I was using that version

Comment: In the godot 3.x LTS branch there is code for `SceneTree::_update_group_order` that allows sorting nodes by process_priority first, but this is not used when handling key input. So no, not possible in godot 3.5 either.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of `_unhandled_key_input` being called does not seem possible, but if you really need it, you could create your own version.

Create a custom `_unhandled_key_input` with a different name on your nodes, and from the real `_unhandled_key_input` of a root node call your custom function on all child nodes that provide it, in the order you like. (Have not tested this though)